# Processing large quantities of data by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data filter which contains a comboboxes for year, month, country and city. All of items in comboboxes has a choose All (All years, All months, All countries and All cities).

When I choose a filter, I send data to server and I get JSON object with data, which is processed by JQuery.

The problem comes if you select all the data - server would return a JSON object with thirty thousand records (and more) and browser, including animated gig (loader), freeze and everything takes too long.

this is a HTML of data filter (some select are filled by AJAX)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" data-label="Filter data"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3" data-label="Year"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" data-label="Month"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" data-label="Country"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" data-label="City"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select id="cmbYear">
                    <option value="0" data-label="All years"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select id="cmbMonth">
                    <option value="0" data-label="All year"></option>
                    <option value="1" data-label="January"></option>
                    <option value="2" data-label="February"></option>
                    <option value="3" data-label="March"></option>
                    <option value="4" data-label="April"></option>
                    <option value="5" data-label="May"></option>
                    <option value="6" data-label="June"></option>
                    <option value="7" data-label="July"></option>
                    <option value="8" data-label="August"></option>
                    <option value="9" data-label="September"></option>
                    <option value="10" data-label="October"></option>
                    <option value="11" data-label="November"></option>
                    <option value="12" data-label="December"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select id="cmbCountry">
   <option value="0" data-label="All countries"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select id="cmbCity">
                <option value="0" data-label="All cities"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="btnFilterData" data-label="Filter data" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is a JQuery Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnFilterData').click(function () {
        GetFilteredData();
    });
});

function GetFilteredData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some-file.php',
        data: {
            year: $('#cmbYear').val(),
            month: $('#cmbMonth').val(),
            countryid: $('#cmbCountry').val(),
            cityid: $('#cmbCity').val()
        },
        type: 'post',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsError) {
                ShowErrorDialog(data.Error);
            }
            else {
                $('#tableRawData').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
                if (data.Data != null) {


           for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.Data).length; i++) {
                    var obj = data.Data[i];

                    var newRow = '<tr><td>' + obj.Date+ '</td><td>' + obj.Country + '</td><td>' + obj.City + '</td><td>' + obj.Loan+ '</td><td>' + obj.Paid+ '</td><td>' + obj.Remains+ '</td><td data-label="' + obj.Note + '"></td></tr>';
                    $('#tableRawData').append(newRow);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        HideWaitDialog();
    }
});
```

Is any way how to make processing faster or more effective? In ideal way without freezing a browser and animated loader...

Comment: Maybe add paging to the results so only a few are shown at a time?  I doubt any user is going to need to *simultaneously* see 30,000 records.

Comment: Easy enough to set some  sort of limit and if more results exist than limit return message that tells user to narrow down filter

Comment: in fact is not necessary show all records. this is only the outer limit :-) but my customer want to have possibility to show all data (i mean that is not right solution, but he want it)

Comment: That's too many elements to put in page.... use pagination or scroll loading that doesn't add all the elements at once

Comment: If the customer wants *all* data, make them download it or have it available as a Google sheet.

Comment: I think pagination is not practical when there are 30,000 results.. as @Mottie suggested if you results exceed a certain limit better provide a different data access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your code, and I agree with the comments on paging, but, if you REALLY want to keep the things the way they are here are some optimizations I found

- You are calling `$('#tableRawData')` at each iteration but this it will be the same at each iteration. You are wasting computation power here. You should put this in a variable at the beginning of your loop. By doing this you will improve the performance of your code by **15%**
- append is a complex function which involves DOM manipulation, you should 't use it as little as possible. A trick would be to accumulate your HTML in a string and call append at the end of the loop. By doing this you will be **12 times faster** than my previous solution
- jQuery append parse your string and decompose it do DOM elements and append them to the DOM tree. This operation has a high cost. What you could do is to as the browser to parse the string and append it. It will be faster because it 's native and highly optimized code and there will be no interaction between jQuery, javascript, and the DOM tree. If you do it will be **1.7 times faster** than my previous solution

I put the code snippets in a jsperf so you can test it on your operating system and browser : http://jsperf.com/creating-a-large-table-with-jquery

All the tests are for 10000 rows.

Applying all the optimizations on my browser make the code **26x faster** than yours

As a funny conclusion : the answer to you question :

> Processing large quantities of data by JQuery

is :

> Do not use jQuery ;)

Comment: Facing same issue and resolve. But i face another problem. I'm using select2() plugin for dropdown that fetch result via ajax call from database. If I append string with table after loop, select2() didn't appear. So i've to append string (<tr></tr>) inside the loop and then call for select2() function for each row inside loop which cause performance issue. How should I resolve it?